# How do I allow rwx access to a specific group with ACLs?

Tags: permissions, acl

How do I grant read, write and execute to specific group?

What I did:

```
adduser test
addgroup developer
setfacl -m g:developer:rwx /opt/spago41/
```

When I login as test I can't run:

```
startup.sh in /opt/spago41/
```

Is the `setfacl` command not working?

Comment: Have you added `test` user in `developer` group ?

Comment: @SHW yes sir !!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you were missing the "recursive" parameter:

> setfacl -Rm g:developer:rwx /opt/spago41/

Answer (score 0):

```
# useradd -G developers test
```

Use the below command if ther user `test` is already created.

`# usermod -a -G Developer test`

This will solve your problem. As you haven't appended the user `test` in `developer` group, and you set ACL to group `developer`, which doesn't have user `test` in it. 
Attribution: [SHW](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4843/shw)

Answer (score 0):

**Check 1#**

As @SHW suggested in comments check that test user is exists or not in Developer Group

**Check 2#**

File System mounted with `acl` option or not.

from `man mount`:

> ```
>    acl|noacl
>           Support POSIX Access Control Lists (or not).
> ```

you can check using `mount` command